# WIndows API for enumerating bound but unconnected sockets

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

In newer versions of the 'netstat' utility for Windows there's a command line option '-q' that shows bound but unconnected sockets.

The output about such sockets are shown like this

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:4294           0.0.0.0:0              BOUND
TCP    0.0.0.0:8054           0.0.0.0:0              BOUND
TCP    0.0.0.0:8840           0.0.0.0:0              BOUND
```

I use GetExtendedTcpTable in a netstat-like program to monitor the resources (memory, handles, threads, connections) consumed by some applications (identified either by pid or by the ".exe" name), but I believe this API only shows information for **connections**, not for sockets, and because of that, it doesn't provide information for bound but unconnected sockets.

So, which Windows API can be used to capture this information in a C++ program ?

Comment: Use dumpbin.exe /imports on an executable file to discover what magic api it might be using.  Not hard to see InternalGetBoundTcpEndpointTable().  It is, erm, mentioned.  Maybe it will get documented some day, don't hold your breath for it.

Comment: @Hans Passant: so, do you have any suggestion as to how I could implement the functionality I've asked, short of disassembling  InternalGetBoundTcpEndpointTable to guess it's parameters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows doesn't currently have any documented or supported APIs for querying bound connections. The only alternative is using these two undocumented functions:

```
ULONG WINAPI InternalGetBoundTcpEndpointTable(
    _Out_ PMIB_TCPTABLE2* BoundTcpTable,
    _In_ PVOID HeapHandle,
    _In_opt_ ULONG HeapFlags
    );

ULONG WINAPI InternalGetBoundTcp6EndpointTable(
    _Out_ PMIB_TCP6TABLE2* BoundTcp6Table,
    _In_ PVOID HeapHandle,
    _In_opt_ ULONG HeapFlags
    );
```

Example:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")

#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

ULONG WINAPI InternalGetBoundTcpEndpointTable(
    _Out_ PMIB_TCPTABLE2* BoundTcpTable,
    _In_ PVOID HeapHandle,
    _In_opt_ ULONG HeapFlags
    );

ULONG WINAPI InternalGetBoundTcp6EndpointTable(
    _Out_ PMIB_TCP6TABLE2* BoundTcp6Table,
    _In_ PVOID HeapHandle,
    _In_opt_ ULONG HeapFlags
    );

void main()
{
    PMIB_TCPTABLE2 boundTcpTable;
    PMIB_TCP6TABLE2 boundTcp6Table;

    if (InternalGetBoundTcpEndpointTable(&boundTcpTable, GetProcessHeap(), 0) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        for (ULONG i = 0; i < boundTcpTable->dwNumEntries; i++)
        {
            printf("%lu: %lu\n",
                boundTcpTable->table[i].dwOwningPid,
                boundTcpTable->table[i].dwLocalPort);
        }

        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, boundTcpTable);
    }

    if (InternalGetBoundTcp6EndpointTable(&boundTcp6Table, GetProcessHeap(), 0) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        for (ULONG i = 0; i < boundTcp6Table->dwNumEntries; i++)
        {
            printf("%lu: %lu\n",
                boundTcp6Table->table[i].dwOwningPid,
                boundTcp6Table->table[i].dwLocalPort);
        }

        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, boundTcp6Table);
    }
}
```